# SQL Server sys.tables not capturing correct modify_date

Tags: sql-server, pandas, sqlalchemy, truncate, pandas-to-sql

**Context:** I have an ETL process setup to populate tables in a datawarehouse using a Python script. The script executes a truncate statement via sqlalchemy to empty each of the tables then uses the pandas `.to_sql` method to load fresh source data from a dataframe. See below snippet:

```
engine.execute(sa_text(f'''TRUNCATE TABLE {schema}.{table}''').execution_options(autocommit=True))
df.to_sql(table, con=engine, schema=schema, if_exists='append', index=False, chunksize=chunksize,
          method=method)
```

**Questions:** Strangely, SQL Server's sys.tables **modify_date** column for each table is not capturing the table changes reflecting the up to date modify_date. Can someone please explain to me why this is and how I can modify my Python code and or SQL Server settings to accurately capture the changes in **sys.tables**?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`modify_date` doesn't capture `TRUNCATE` (or any changes *to the data*). From [the documentation on `sys.objects`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/system-catalog-views/sys-objects-transact-sql) (which is where `sys.tables` gets its columns):

> Date the object was last modified by using an ALTER statement. If the object is a table or a view, modify_date also changes when an index on the table or view is created or altered.

SQL Server doesn't track data modifications by default, and it seems you're after tracking specifically just these truncate operations, in which case I would suggest a logging table that your application writes to as each operation succeeds (or fails, I suppose).

Comment: Thanks @aaron. Do you know of any system table that do track changes to the data? I'm hoping I wont need to setup change data capture or something similar.

Comment: No, change data capture, relying on index usage stats DMVs, etc. all have various pitfalls for what you want to track (assuming it's _just_ the truncates you want to track). If you want to capture _all data changes_ then, yes, change data capture, or change tracking, or maybe temporal tables are features you should look at.